# how to install my application OTA in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to download and run my application from the web server.

I think For that i need to place my application .app files in web server.

Perviously i did this for blackberry.

For that i place .cod files in web server,and type url http://1.1.8.1/Downloadmyapp/myapp.aspx in browser,

then my app gets downloaded and by run it,it will run fine.

Is it possible for iphone.If it is how can i done can any one pls suggest me.

pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't how iOS apps are installed. They are installed via the App Store on the device or via syncing with iTunes.

You cannot install an iOS app over the air in the simulator or on the device.

Comment: @Jasarien.I want to install Angry Birds in Iphone Simulator. Is it Possible..?

Comment: You mean,it is not possible to install on simulator.OK.Thanks for reply

Comment: That is correct. Unless you have the source code to compile it for simulator yourself, or a precompiled simulator build, it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

with the iOS 4.0 update it's possible to install the beta versionsof apps OTA to devices.. the varios options available to you are here http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2011/01/7-tools-for-ota-ios-beta-testing.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with iOS 4. All that is required is a manifest XML file, and a signed IPA file. You can read all you need to know about this here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW2